# Worf as a member of the house of Martok

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, worf

In ST:DS9 5:21, Martok offers Worf to join the House of Martok:

> MARTOK: The House of Martok would be honored to welcome the Son of Mogh into our family.... as a warrior--and as a brother.

Worf accepts, but his actual status in the House of Martok is never established. As a Son of Mogh, what is he in the House of Martok, and what is the equivalent in our society? Is he a warrior? A brother? A servant? A serf? Some variation of all of these?

Comment: He's Martok's "brother".

Comment: The answer (a "brother") is clearly in the quote, as mentioned by Valorum.

Comment: or possibly as a son or nephew - but even if 'brother', certainly not on equal footing with Martok. since Martok's wife apparently had the authority to quash Worf's marriage

Comment: Worf had a lot of authority over his brother in the House of Mogh, so it would stand to reason that Worf's relationship to the House of Martok is the same as Kurn's in the House of Mogh

Comment: @Rebel-Scum The quote’s context—“as a warrior—and as a brother”—suggests that the terms “warrior” and “brother” are colloquial rather than titular. As such, his place in Martok’s House is never clearly defined. Not, for that matter, is the Klingon familial hierarchical structure—a non-family member joining a House would likely not have the same status as a full family member.

Comment: @Yehuda In general I would agree, but Worf is not just another random warrior who joined Martok's house. Instead, they were close friends and colleagues, Worf has saved Martok's life more than once and eventually even helped him become Chancellor (well after this episode though).